# Setting up Apache. The var folder cannot be written to

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

Currently installed the LAMP stack using `tasksel` but I've run into a problem. The location where the website folder is located is not easily writable. It's a pain in the keister to do anything.

```
/var/www
```

Since I'm new to LAMP on Linux, maybe I'm doing things incorrectly. This is for my dev machine ONLY - not production.

What is the workflow if I want to develop a PHP application and run it locally on Apache? I can't even edit files on the default path, because of permissions from Linux.

Any suggestions? Maybe I can create a folder on my Home directory and tell Apache to use that instead?

What do the regular's do?

Comment: Why isn't it "easily" writable?

Comment: I would need to `sudo` for every single change I need to do. That's a gigantic waste of time.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Belongs on serverfault.

Comment: @SergioTapia - Change the permissions to however you want.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you, a standard user, trying to add `php` files to the web server for it to execute? Or are you trying to write `php` scripts that the webserver will use to modify its own directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the "nicest" way to do this is to change the value of DocumentRoot inside Apache to a directory that is writable by you, or to create an alias:

open conf file (or default site), in debian/ubuntu this is located, in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default and edit DocumentRoot and other references to that directory (/var/www):

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/Projects
<Directory /home/user/Projects>
```

After that restart apache (sudo services apache2 restart) and then you will get it working in a writable place by you. There is only one inconvenience with this: You will have to add apache to your user group in order to give apache write permissions for uploading/creating files.

Hope this helps!
Gonzalo G.

Comment: I say the nicest, just because I'm imagining that this is your "development" environment :-). In any other case I will definitely suggest that you go with something like @sarnold replied

Comment: This is what I was asking about, I guess my question wasn't as clear as I thought.

Comment: I can't save any changes I write to that file. The save button is disabled. :/

Comment: That's because the file needs to be edited with root rights, try with "sudo gedit" or something like that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Unix filesystem permissions are there to provide a *safe* and *secure* computing experience. It really is best to work with the permissions to model your work flow and only occasionally elevate privileges, because elevated privileges are when problems can happen too easily. Following the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) will prevent many security flaws from having severe consequences.

You've got a directory that stores your static web content, your executable web content (and maybe web logs?) in `/var/www/`. It should not be owned by the Apache user, nor should it be owned by your user account. `root` (or something more specific, such as `www-content`) make sense.

You do not want the running web server to have the ability to modify its own content -- many PHP worms spread this way. If your web server can only write into log files it'll be nearly impossible to exploit for any privileges. If it can also write to a database pipe, it'll be able to do whatever the database privileges will allow it to do -- read or write data at will, or perhaps just read certain data in specific ways. If it can write to a directory to store images for later serving, it might be abused to host content you don't want, but it at least cannot influence the larger site. If it can write to any of its content, an attacker could use it to persistently modify its own content and potentially attack your users.

You probably also don't want the `/var/www` directory or any of its children to be owned by your user account, either -- you don't want a Firefox, Evolution, Pidgin, or Spotify flaw to have write access to your web server content.

So the better approach is to do all the development work in your home directory somewhere, on files owned by you, and served by another web server that runs under your own user account on an unprivileged port bound to accept only `localhost` connections. Once you've developed the software to a state you like, you can distribute the software to the *production* web server.

The distribution is often done via a tool like `git` -- you `git push` your development work to a repository, and then when you wish to deploy a new version, you log into the account that owns the `/var/www` directory and use `git pull` to download a new version. This is a little complicated but having a real source control system is well worth the extra effort.

If you want something simpler, you could simply use `sudo(1)` to elevate to `www-content` privileges and copy the content over; it might look something like this:

```
cd ~/projects/website
sudo -u www-content tar cf - . | (cd /var/www/ && tar xvf -)
```

This way, the live *production* files are owned by `www-content` and cannot be written to by the web server. Your user account does not have permission to modify them either, except when you run the `sudo` command explicitly. (Setting up `sudo(8)` correctly can be some work; if you're a single person development shop, maybe doing these steps as `root` instead would work fine.)

If you have a few users who want to work on the web content *live*, and you trust them and the software they run completely, then you can use *group ownership* to skip some of the steps. (This might be fine for hobbyist use, but I wouldn't want to use this to run a business.) Add each person's user account to a specific group, say `www-editors`, and make `/var/www` and children group-owned by `www-editors`, use the BSD groups behavior (`man 8 mount`, look for `bsdgroups`, for full details; it requires changing mount options in `/etc/fstab` and setting the `setgid` bit on the directories). This gives you, and all users in the group, the ability to edit the files without any intermediate steps. This is both convenient and dangerous. Use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions in linux via the terminal like this chmod 777=w r x write read execute for all users chmod 775 w r x for current user .
Do you have su acess on the server if you do you can use this if you don't you can't change permissions.

This is a example

Add Read, Write, Execute to User and Group

Lets say we want taps.sh to have all permissions to those who are lucky enough to be in our group, or be us. To do so:

`

```
enter code here`$ chmod +rwx taps.sh
$ ls -l taps.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 erik erik 1014 2010-10-28 13:30 taps.sh
```

Good luck

Comment: Since `taps.sh`'s group is `erik`, this is pretty harmless, but in general you do _not_ want executable content to also be writable. That's a gaping security flaw waiting to happen...

Comment: Making any directory rwx to everything is generally a bad idea. It'd be better to have the add the Group to the User and then have the Group permissions be whatever is needed.